# Visibility Widget Occupies Area In Row Widget?

Tags: flutter

In my code, the third Container should not be included since it is wrapped in the `Visibility` widget. This is what I have tried,

```
 Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
     children: <Widget>[
         Container(...),
         Container(...),
         Visibility(visible:false, child: Container(...))
     ]
)
```

What it should look like:

[image: what it should look like]

What actually happened:

[image: what actually happened]

Comment: The `Visibility` widget sets its child's opacity to 0 when the `visible` parameter is set to true. So the child is still there, it's only not visible to the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Visibility documentation:

> By default, the visible property controls whether the child is included in the subtree or not; when it is not visible, the replacement child (typically a zero-sized box) is included instead.

This shows that just because a widget is wrapped in the `Visibility` widget, doesn't mean it doesn't exist in the widget tree.

The best way to go about this would be to make the widget `null` so it isn't included in the widget tree.

```
bool notNull(Object o) => o != null;
bool isVisible = false;
...

 Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
     children: <Widget>[
         Container(...),
         Container(...),
         isVisible? Container(...) : null,
     ].where(notNull).toList(),
)
```

Or you could optionally create the list in a build method so that you can simply add your widget to the list if a certain condition is met.

```
Builder(
  build: (context) {
     bool isVisible = false;
     List<Widget> _children = [
       Container(...),
       Container(...),
     ];

     if (isVisible) {
        _children.add(Container(...)); // Optional widget
     }

     return Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
       children: _children,
     );
  }
),
```

Comment: I think the first option rocks! So simple and effective

Comment: @blackkara I know right! It's much more convenient than adding a Builder widget. 
Originally from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3783

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your widget is not visible, but it does counts when calculating the spacing.

You can try using a builder

```
Builder(
  build: (context) {
     var children = [
       Container(...),
       Container(...),
     ];

     if (your condition) {
        childern.add(Container(...));
     }

     return Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
       children: children
     );
  }
);
```